# PHP daemon process to submit post-dated status updates to Facebook, Twitter, etc

Tags: php, cron, daemon

I am building an app that lets users link their facebook, twitter, linkedin accounts to my app and than post updates to all these sites through my app. Additionally user can 'post-date' status updates. They can set a date and time to their update, and which will cause the update to be posted to the requested sites only at the specified date and not immediately.

I have got this working fine with a **cron** job that pulls out all updates that have not been posted yet (there's a flag indicating whether an update has been posted or not in the DB) and then posting it. I run this process every minute using cron.
Now my issue is that, with enough updates set to the same time, I'll have problems with PHP maxing out the execution time. My immediate work around has been to get all updates which have a `post_timestamp < current_timestamp` and try to post them; so that if for a particular minute, some updates have not been sent, the next cron run will try to send it if it is still inside the max execution time limit.

I know this is a very lame ass way of achieving what I want. Hence I plan to have some kind of a daemon process which keeps on running and posts all post-dated updates.
What's the best way of achieving this? I also need this daemon approach for another project I am working on. any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated... :P

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Gearman is probably what you are looking for: http://gearman.org/

Answer (score 0):

I've written a number of PHP-based systems that do similar things - long running processes that can't be run from a frequent Cron-job as it cannot be allowed to run concurrently.

It's a three-stage process.

1. An initial script is run on demand, or when a server is restarted (see [vixie-cron @reboot](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/blog/archives/001021.html)). This just calls the 2nd part.
2. A looping script that calls your PHP script to send all actions who are due, but not sent yet
3. the script to send the content from the database.

The 2nd part of that is quite easy.

```
#!/bin/sh
# this file is runSocialSend.sh

BASEURL=http://alister.example.com
URL=$BASE/path/actions/send-to-social-sites.php
# don't store the output
WGET="/usr/bin/wget  -O /dev/null -- "
# wait this many seconds between runs
SLEEP=20

# could also just run it from the CLI - php -f ..../send-to-social-sites.php
$WGET $URL
sleep $SLEEP
# and loop round again to restart...
exec $0
```

The first part to run the above properly is even simpler.

```
#!/bin/sh

killall runSocialSend.sh
nohup ./runSocialSend.sh > /dev/null &
```

Literally, kill any other instances of the runSocialSend.sh script, and then restart it, disconnecting from the 'console', running it in the background.